# ffmpeg disable scaler / rtp stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have some problem with ffmpeg scaler. I receive (via sdp) VP9 video stream and then - transcode to H264. Main stream (input) can changes resolution on fly, but output - cannot. I want to change output resolution based on input resolution / on fly.

```
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x563b9c008cc0] Setting 'video_size' to value '240x320'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x563b9c008cc0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x563b9c008cc0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/90000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x563b9c008cc0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x563b9c008cc0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x563b9c008cc0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '90000/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x563b9c008cc0] w:240 h:320 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 fr:90000/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0x563b9c009800] Setting 'w' to value '480'
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0x563b9c009800] Setting 'h' to value '640'
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0x563b9c009800] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0x563b9c009800] w:480 h:640 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0x563b9c085240] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x563b9c060fc0] query_formats: 5 queried, 4 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[scaler_out_0_0 @ 0x563b9c009800] w:240 h:320 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:480 h:640 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
```

As you can see, scaler sets width and height to started main stream resolution values (480x640). 
How can I "disable" scaler or set it to set width and height from input stream and respect it on fly?

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -i test.sdp -vsync 2 -an -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -thread_type slice -profile:v baseline -threads 16 -bufsize 80M -f rtp rtp://232.3.4.5:7588
```

Comment: Not possible. Except for VP9 output, output streams have to have fixed resolution.

Comment: @Gyan, you are wrong, gstreamer works like a charm in this situation (dynamic resolution via h264 and vp9)

Comment: Your Q is about ffmpeg, not gstreamer.

Comment: @Gyan, I thought you talk about codec libs limitation or something like this. Sorry ;)